Constructing operator $E_1 \otimes E_2 \otimes \cdots $
I am working with the Bose-Hubbard model and I want to construct the following operator as described below.
I have $L$ lattice sites where I want to construct this operator $e^{i*\phi*N_{R1}}$ where $N_{R1}$ is the number operator for the first half of the lattice sites.
Where $N_{R1}$ is $$n_{1} \otimes n_{2} \otimes n_{3} \otimes \cdots n_{siteno} \otimes Iden_{siteno+1} \otimes Iden_{siteno+2} \otimes \cdots Iden_{L}$$
$Iden$ is the identity matrix whose dimension is $(nmax+1, nmax+1)$
$n_{j}$ is number operator for the - it is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are {0, 1, 2, .., nmax} where nmax is the maximum no. of particles each site can hold
where $j = \{1, 2, \dots \}$
For example, $nmax = 2$, then $n_{j} = diags\{0,1,2\}$
For two-sites Bose-Hubbard model, the phase_difference operator I need is
$$e^{i*\phi*n_{1}} \otimes Iden$$
For four sites, the operator I need is $$e^{i*\phi*n_{1}} \otimes e^{i*\phi*n_{1}} \otimes Iden \otimes Iden$$

I kind of don't want to go through the code. Instead, does this do the trick?KroneckerProduct @@ Join[Table[DiagonalMatrix@Exp[I \[Phi] Range[0, nmax]], {siteno}], Table[IdentityMatrix[nmax + 1], {siteno}]]

@march, yes it gives the correct answer. May I know how the Table for identitymatrix works as it uses siteno?

Table[a, {siteno}] is short-hand for Table[a, {n, 1, siteno}], useful for when the entries don't depend on the index n, which is the case here, since each entry is either $e^{i\phi \hat{n}}$ or just the identity.

Okay, I get it now. I use siteno for only replacing E operator with Iden. Here, you are creating a sequence of operators and then joining them and applying kroneckerproduct on it. Thanks
